# Does statsmodels anova_lm require the same assumptions as the scipy f_oneway anova?

Tags: python, scipy, statsmodels, anova

The f_oneway anova test in scipy has three assumptions:

1. The samples are independent.
2. Each sample is from a normally distributed population.
3. The population standard deviations of the groups are all equal. This property is known as homoscedasticity.

Do I have to consider these three when I use the statsmodels kind of anova?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; the assumptions of ANOVA are statistical concerns, rather than programming concerns. No matter what library is implementing the ANOVA, the same 3 assumptions you listed out apply because of the way the underlying math works.

If one of those 3 assumptions is violated, there are some things you can try to either salvage the ANOVA or use a different technique, depending on which assumptions is violated and how extreme the violation is. More info on those methods here: https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/one-way-anova-statistical-guide-3.php